# != operator syntax for switch statements in c#

Tags: c#, enums, syntax, switch-statement

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax for the != operator for switch statements. Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
 public enum Foo { A, B, C };
 public Foo foo;
 void Bar()
 {
     switch (foo)
     {
         case !Foo.A:
             DoStuff();
             break;
     }
 }
```

So, in this case, "DoStuff()" if foo != A;

Comment: `case Foo.A: break; default: doStuff(); break`? C#8 and newer have some pattern matching, but I can't see the need in this case unless it's just an illustrating example.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, this is just an illustrating example. The real switch statement I'm trying to use this for has several more cases, and the default case is already being used for something else.

Comment: @FaffyWaffles That sounds like you should not be using a `switch` statement then. A `switch` statement comparing an integer value to constants is compiled to a native jump-table which is `O(1)` and crazy-fast (whereas `if` statements are checked in-sequence, which is slow), which means an exhaustive `switch` requires _exactly and only_ 1 case to match for any input value (including `default` though) but what you described sounds like you want to evaluate multiple cases for a single input - which you cannot do with `switch` (at least without `goto case` or fallthrough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is what [@JoachimIsaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) mentioned in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73245224/operator-syntax-for-switch-statements-in-c-sharp#comment129355799_73245224):

```
switch (foo)
{
    case Foo.A:
        // Do nothing
        break;
    default:
        DoStuff();
        break;
}
```

If you are using C# 9 or higher you can use `not`:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case not Foo.A:
        DoStuff();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with C# 9, you can use `not`, which is a kind of [relational pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#relational-patterns):

```
 switch (foo)
 {
     case not Foo.A:
         DoStuff();
         break;
 }
```

In older versions, you need to use an empty `Foo.A` case to exclude it, and `DoStuff` in the `default` case:

```
 switch (foo)
 {
     case Foo.A:
         break;
     default:
         DoStuff();
         break;
 }
```

Comment: _Neat_, I didn't know about this; after checking it out in Linqpad I can say it's nice that the C# compiler is also smart enough to raise compiler errors if you have conflicting relational `case` lines (e.g. it won't let you compile this: `switch( x ) { case 1: return GetFor1(); case 2: return GetFor2(); case not 2: return Hmm(); }` ).

Answer (score 3):

What Sweeper and Bill Tür say, but also:

## if

`if(foo != Foo.A) DoStuff();`

## case guard

(See Case guards in [Selection statements (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements#case-guards))

```
foreach(var f in Enum.GetValues<Foo>())
    switch (f) 
    {
      case var x when x != Foo.A:
            Console.WriteLine($"{f}: Not A");
            break;
      default: 
            Console.WriteLine($"{f}: A");
            break;
    }
//A: A
//B: Not A
//C: Not A
```